# Why does ROS2 custom message colcon build give include file errors?

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS2, but very familiar with ROS1.

I am doing a very minor tweak of the ROS2 tutorial [Creating custom ROS 2 msg and srv files](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html) and it fails to build. *The base tutorial code works fine.* I don't care about `srv` so I got rid of that. And I added a new message.

The new message I added is named `Complex.msg`, and is shown below

```
Header header
Num num
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(tutorial_interfaces)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package( REQUIRED)

find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/Num.msg"
  "msg/Complex.msg"
 )

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

And my `package.xml` is unchanged from default shown in the [ROS2 galactic tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html).

When I try to build this slightly tweaked tutorial I get build errors shown below. I *suspect* that my new message requires changes to `CMakeLists.txt` and/or `package.xml`. If so, can you please guide what changes I need.

### Colcon build error

`colcon build --packages-select tutorial_interfaces`

```
Starting >>> tutorial_interfaces
--- stderr: tutorial_interfaces                             
In file included from .../colcon_ws/build/tutorial_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/tutorial_interfaces/msg/detail/complex__functions.h:19,
                 from .../colcon_ws/build/tutorial_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/tutorial_interfaces/msg/detail/complex__functions.c:4:
.../colcon_ws/build/tutorial_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c/tutorial_interfaces/msg/detail/complex__struct.h:22:10: fatal error: tutorial_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include "tutorial_interfaces/msg/detail/header__struct.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

...More errors like above

Summary: 0 packages finished [3.30s]
  1 package failed: tutorial_interfaces
  1 package had stderr output: tutorial_interface
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393332/why-does-ros2-custom-message-colcon-build-give-include-file-errors?/) by [ajayvohra2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/91833/ajayvohra2005/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're missing a few things compared to a similar messages package I got working:

- `find_package` for `std_msgs` where the header field comes from
- `DEPENDENCIES std_msgs` in the `rosidl_generate_interfaces` command (see [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Single-Package-Define-And-Use-Interface.html#use-an-interface-from-the-same-package))
- Put `std_msgs/Header` in the `.msg` file instead of just `Header`

The relevant piece of your CMakeLists should be then:

```
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/Num.msg"
  "msg/Complex.msg"
  DEPENDENCIES std_msgs
 )
```

Then, also put `<depend>std_msgs</depend>` in `package.xml` if you haven't already.

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2021-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ajayvohra2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/91833/ajayvohra2005/) on 2021-12-26**:
I had tried this before, except for `std_msgs/Header` instead of just `Header`.  These steps work.